# No effect from ZoomIn in QTextEdit after font size change

Tags: python, qt4, pyside

This code runs a little window with a toolbar and a QTextEdit area.

If you highlight 'bananas' and change the font size, then using zoom from either the toolbar buttons or CTRL + mouse wheel will only resize 'apples'.  Anyone know why?

```
from PySide import QtGui, QtCore

class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.textEdit = Editor(self)
        self.toolBar  = QtGui.QToolBar(self)
        self.addToolBar(self.toolBar)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.textEdit)
        self.textEdit.setHtml('<font color=blue>apples bananas</font>')

        # Zoom
        self.actionZoomIn  = QtGui.QAction('Zoom In',  self)
        self.actionZoomOut = QtGui.QAction('Zoom Out', self)
        self.toolBar.addAction(self.actionZoomIn)
        self.toolBar.addAction(self.actionZoomOut)
        self.actionZoomIn.triggered.connect(self.onZoomInClicked)
        self.actionZoomOut.triggered.connect(self.onZoomOutClicked)

        # Font Size
        self.comboSize = QtGui.QComboBox(self.toolBar)
        self.toolBar.addWidget(self.comboSize)
        self.comboSize.addItem('0')
        self.comboSize.addItem('10')
        self.comboSize.addItem('18')
        self.comboSize.addItem('30')
        self.comboSize.addItem('48')
        self.comboSize.setCurrentIndex(1)
        self.comboSize.activated[str].connect(self.textSize)

    def textSize(self, pointSize):
        pointSize = int(pointSize)
        if pointSize > 0:
            fmt = QtGui.QTextCharFormat()
            fmt.setFontPointSize(pointSize)
            self.mergeFormatOnWordOrSelection(fmt)

    def mergeFormatOnWordOrSelection(self, format):
        cursor = self.textEdit.textCursor()
        if not cursor.hasSelection():
            cursor.select(QtGui.QTextCursor.WordUnderCursor)

        cursor.mergeCharFormat(format)
        self.textEdit.mergeCurrentCharFormat(format)

    def onZoomInClicked(self):
        self.textEdit.zoom(+1)

    def onZoomOutClicked(self):
        self.textEdit.zoom(-1)

class Editor(QtGui.QTextEdit):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Editor, self).__init__(parent)
        self.zoomValue = 0

    def zoom(self, delta):
        zoomIncrement = 3

        if delta < 0:
            zoomIncrement = 0 - zoomIncrement

        self.zoomIn(zoomIncrement)
        self.zoomValue = self.zoomValue + zoomIncrement

        print "self.zoomValue", self.zoomValue

    def wheelEvent(self, event):
        if (event.modifiers() & QtCore.Qt.ControlModifier):
            self.zoom(event.delta())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication([])
    window = MainWindow()
    window.resize(400, 180)
    window.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default implementation of `QTextEdit.zoomIn/Out` simply changes the `pointSize` of the base font for the text-edit.

The method used in the example to change font size wraps the selected word in a `span` tag and uses inline css to set the `font-size` property to a fixed value. This means that when the text-edit is subsequently zoomed, only the unchanged text will be affected.

It would be possible overcome this problem by using relative font sizes. However, it looks like only a limted subset of [css properties](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/richtext-html-subset.html#css-properties) is supported, so its only possible to set imprecise values like `small`, `large`, etc.

This can be implemented in the example by making the following changes:

```
    # Font Size
    self.comboSize = QtGui.QComboBox(self.toolBar)
    self.toolBar.addWidget(self.comboSize)
    self.comboSize.addItem('small')
    self.comboSize.addItem('medium')
    self.comboSize.addItem('large')
    self.comboSize.addItem('x-large')
    self.comboSize.addItem('xx-large')
    self.comboSize.setCurrentIndex(1)
    self.comboSize.activated[int].connect(self.textSize)

def textSize(self, size):
    fmt = QtGui.QTextCharFormat()
    fmt.setProperty(QtGui.QTextFormat.FontSizeAdjustment, size - 1)
    self.mergeFormatOnWordOrSelection(fmt)
```